Remove calcium deposits between panes of vinyl sash window
A friend moved into an apartment with vinyl sash windows that have white deposits on the inside faces of the double glazing.   I think these are manufactured sealed units that have failed.
I hope a two-part question is not too inappropriate here but they are strongly related.

Is there anything to be done?   If I owned these windows I would just be sad for a while and then replace them.  I'm pretty sure it can't be fixed.  But my friend is a tenant and the landlord is not going to replace them.  Have you encountered a way to repair this or at least stop it getting worse?
What is it?   Condensation from air does not contain minerals.  And I know this isn't science-SE but to the extent it can be answered in a relevant way:  What could cause white deposits on the inside of a sealed double glazing unit?


To remove calcium deposit ginger and baking soda

One hack to fix is to drill small holes to vent the space between double glazing.  Probably also not something landlord would like.  Condensation in a town/city is probably not pure.

@crip659 her landlord has not objected to any hole-drilling so far including holes for a TV bracket but I think destroying the front windows would cross a line.  :) Even if they are crap.

@jay613   Most of the hacks recommend drilling from the sides/bottom/top in between the panes for ventilation.  Hard to do for windows in a wall.

@crip659 I didn't realize that was a serious suggestion.  The windows are typical vinyl sash ones, they come out of the wall easily so I'll look into doing that.  Ventilating the inside won't remove dirt from the glass but if we see a serious condensation problem later in the year, maybe that's an idea.

If it is tried, it is recommended to place steel wool into the holes to keep out bugs.  I would search for it before doing anything, to think about trying it.  As with most hacks it is 50/50 of being snakeoil.

Generally self servicing of double panes is not recommended and can be dangerous.
In most all instances the only proper and logical solution to this problem is replacement of the glass.
What exactly is the chemical makeup of the organism fogging the glass is moot, since realistically cleaning it is out of the question.
Trying to rectify this problem as a tenant will be much more likely to result in the tenant paying for new windows, rather than a clean glass.
